# Why is setinterval animation not working?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I have tried to create the animation of a cat walking using setInterval and a function that changes style property left. This does however not work. There is no animation. And I have done everything correctly so I don't know why It's not working.

````
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Challenge: Catwalk</title>
        <style>
            #cat {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <!-- Cat walking GIF from: http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/graphics.html -->
        <img id="cat" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/misc/cat-walk.gif">
    </div>

  <script>
  var catEl = document.getElementById("cat");

  function walkTheCat(){
      catEl.style.left=parseFloat(catEl.style.left)+40+"px"
  };
  setInterval(walkTheCat,1000)
  </script>

    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: avoid javascript for animations. use css animations.

Comment: `catEl.style.left = (parseFloat(catEl.style.left) || 0) + 40 + "px"` ... because the element itself has no `left` style value - CSS doesn't add style to the element style

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use a counter. `left = left + 40` and that will ensure the cat animates across the screen.

[image]

```js
var left = 0;
function walkTheCat() {
  catEl.style.left = left;
  left = left + 40;
};

setInterval(walkTheCat, 1000)
```

I've recorded a screencast showing you how I solved this. You can find a [highlight of the solution here](https://app.paircast.io/replay/26b5967d-99ae-4755-9486-c278483c5c56#211040).

---

`catEl.style.left` does not provide the css property. See me [try to log it here](https://app.paircast.io/replay/26b5967d-99ae-4755-9486-c278483c5c56#97764:110888).

You can loop the cat by detecting when the image breaks `window.innerWidth`. See my [looping cat here](https://app.paircast.io/replay/26b5967d-99ae-4755-9486-c278483c5c56#255240:297189).

Answer (score 0):

Styles set by CSS does not appear in the element's style property. To make it work either change it to use inline style for `left` or use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). I personally think using inline style is simpler:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Challenge: Catwalk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <!-- Cat walking GIF from: http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/graphics.html -->
        <img id="cat" style="left:0px" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/misc/cat-walk.gif">
    </div>

....
```

Comment: or `catEl.style.left = (parseFloat(catEl.style.left) || 0) + 40 + "px"` :p